# What is the Galois Group of $x^4+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and describe the action of the group on the roots of it's polynomial

Tags: finite-fields

I know the Galois Group is cyclic of order 2 and I got the splitting field to be  $\mathbb{F}_9$  but I don't understand how to write the frobenius automorphism that describes the action

Comment: If $q = p^m$ and $F_q$ is an finite extension of $F_p$, the frobenius automorphism of $F_q$ is always just $x \mapsto x^p$.  What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: how would i write the roots as a permutation?

Comment: Maybe what you mean to ask is how you would describe the automorphism as a permutation of the roots? But I still don't understand where your confusion lies.  As the answer below states, if $\alpha$ is a root $\alpha^3$ must be a root and $\alpha^9 = \alpha$.

Comment: The polynomial is separable so there are four roots in the splitting field, say $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\alpha_3$, $\alpha_4$. Because the Galois group is cyclic of order two, and none of the roots are in the prime field, the Frobenius must permute the roots in $(12)(34)$ fashion (a renumbering of the roots may be needed). It isn't transitive because the polynomial is reducible.

Answer (score 0):

The Froebenius automorphism $\sigma : x \mapsto x^3$ swaps the roots since it transforms a root into a root and $\sigma(x) \neq x$ for all $x \notin \mathbb{F}_3$.

And of course $\sigma^2$ is the identity on $\mathbb{F}_9$.

And that's it, the galaois group is $\{\sigma, Id\}$.